# Retrieving seconds since last record

Tags: sql, datediff, intersystems-cache

I thought this would be simple, but I have a problem.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (s,getdate(), max(TimeCreated)) as difference
FROM Ens.MessageHeader
```

My expectation was that this would show the difference between the current time and the timestamp of the most recent record.  If I execute it, I get something lik e `15057` which could possibly be right.  However, the next time I execute it, it is lower.  There haven't been any new records.  Right now it's at `15024`.  Still no new records.  The most recent timestamp is currently `2016-05-13 08:51:16`

The idea is that I can watch this counter and when it resets to zero I know there is a new message.

What am I missing?

**Update** I added some additional data to the query to help see what is going on:

```
SELECT getDate() as now, max(TimeCreated) as latest, DATEDIFF (s,getdate(), max(TimeCreated)) as difference
FROM Ens.MessageHeader
```

Here are a couple result sets:

```
now                  latest               difference  
-------------------  -------------------  ----------  
2016-05-13 09:50:45  2016-05-13 08:51:16  14431       
2016-05-13 09:52:29  2016-05-13 08:51:16  14327       
2016-05-13 09:52:50  2016-05-13 08:51:16  14306
```

Comment: When I execute the same code on my own table that has a date value, I get a negative number of seconds back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gotcha here has to do with the order of the arguments in your call to `DATEDIFF()` AND the fact that `TimeCreated` is a UTC timestamp that gets converted to local time in some situations, but it looks like it is not being converted when inside `DATEDIFF`. So your query as written looks like it is returning `MAX(TimeCreated + UTC_offset) - getdate()`, which is a positive number that is getting smaller.

As @Gordon Linoff's answer states, you should have `MAX(TimeCreated)` as the second argument to `DATEDIFF` as that is the starting time for the diff. You also likely want to wrap that in the `%EXTERNAL` function to make 110% sure that it's being converted to local time before running the comparison:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, %EXTERNAL(MAX(TimeCreated)), getdate())
FROM Ens.MessageHeader
```

The above query gives me the results I'd expect as we are comparing the two times in the right order and in the same time zone!

All that said, I am not sure whether the `DATEDIFF()` behaviour about taking the pre-conversion value is intended or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is curious.  What is happening is that the `TimeCreated` is in the "future". `DATEDIFF(x, <exp1>, <exp2>)` calculates the difference of `<exp2> - <exp1>`.

So, if `TimeCreate` is supposed to be in the past, then you can try:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, max(TimeCreated), getdate())
FROM Ens.MessageHeader;
```

You'll then get a negative number and wonder what is happening.  As more seconds go by, the negative number goes toward zero, because the current date/time is getting closer to `max(TimeCreated)`.

My guess is that you have a time zone issue.  Or, you have some bias that influences `TimeCreated`.  You may want to [review other ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) of getting the current date/time value.